# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'cat'

Tags: python, pandas

For each `GENE_SYMBOLS` column of a dataframe, merge the rows and retain only unique comma-separated or dash-separated values. After merging the values of each row into a list, obtain only the unique values.

```
geneset = pd.read_csv("genesets.v2023.1.Hs.tsv", sep="\t", index_col=0)
geneset = geneset.loc["GENE_SYMBOLS"] # retrieve only rows with index name "GENE_SYMBOLS"
for i in geneset.columns:
    genes = i.cat(sep=',').tolist()  # Merge all the rows of strings with "," delimiter and store as a list
genes = genes.split(",") # split by the "," delimiter
genes = genes.split("-") # or the "-" delimiter
genes = genes.unique()      # Keep only if not duplicated
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [46], in <cell line: 3>()
      2 geneset = geneset.loc["GENE_SYMBOLS"] # retrieve only rows with index name "GENE_SYMBOLS"
      3 for i in geneset.columns:
----> 4     genes = i.cat(sep=',').tolist()  # Merge all the rows of strings with "," delimiter and store as a list
      5 genes = genes.split(",") # split by the "," delimiter
      6 genes = genes.split("-") # or the "-" delimiter

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'cat'
```

Input:

| STANDARD_NAME | DEURIG_T_CELL_PROLYMPHOCYTIC_LEUKEMIA_UP |
| --- | --- |
| SYSTEMATIC_NAME | M16431 |
| GENE_SYMBOLS | DDR1,CYP2A6,DTX2P1-UPK3BP1-PMS2P11,MARCKSL1 |
| SYSTEMATIC_NAME | M16432 |
| GENE_SYMBOLS | CCL5,IK,ARL6IP5,EIF1AX,PFKP,PJA2,DDR1 |
| SYSTEMATIC_NAME | M16433 |
| GENE_SYMBOLS | PJA2,TLR4,GPNMB,TAGLN,COL1A1,CARMN,CD63 |

Desired output:

```
genes = ['DDR1','CYP2A6','DTX2P1', 'UPK3BP1', 'PMS2P11','MARCKSL1', 'CCL5','IK','ARL6IP5',EIF1AX,PFKP,PJA2, TLR4,GPNMB,TAGLN,COL1A1,CARMN,CD63]
```

Comment: The AttributeError exception tells you all you need to know. Also, bear in mind that if geneses.columns is empty then you'll get a NameError exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
#select rows by index
geneset = geneset.loc["GENE_SYMBOLS"]

#create Series of exploding splitted values
out = (geneset['DEURIG_T_CELL_PROLYMPHOCYTIC_LEUKEMIA_UP']
              .str.split(r'[,-]')
              .explode())

#remove empty strings and only numeric strings
out = out[out.ne('') & ~out.str.isnumeric()]

#get unique list
out = out.unique().tolist()
print(out)

['DDR1', 'CYP2A6', 'DTX2P1', 'UPK3BP1', 'PMS2P11', 'MARCKSL1', 'CCL5', 'IK', 
 'ARL6IP5', 'EIF1AX', 'PFKP', 'PJA2', 'TLR4', 'GPNMB', 'TAGLN', 'COL1A1', 'CARMN', 'CD63']
```

Comment: Thanks! `r'[,-]']` has an extra parenthesis

Comment: Please also remove empty strings `''` and all the strings that only contain numeric values. Thanks!

Comment: @melolili - answer was edited, can you test?

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
# Select only rows with the index name "GENE_SYMBOLS" and transpose the DataFrame
geneset = geneset.loc["GENE_SYMBOLS"].T

# Initialize an empty set to store unique gene symbols
unique_genes = set()

# Iterate over the columns and merge the values
for column in geneset.columns:
    # Split the values by comma or dash and add to the set
    unique_genes.update(column.split(',') + column.split('-'))

# Convert the set to a list and sort it
genes = sorted(list(unique_genes))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need pandas for something so trivial. Just open the file in text mode and parse each line like this:

```
with open('genesets.v2023.1.Hs.tsv') as gs:
    values = {}
    mt = str.maketrans({
        ',': ' ',
        '-': ' '
    })
    for line in gs:
        name, d = line.split()
        if name == 'GENE_SYMBOLS':
            values.update({k: None for k in d.translate(mt).split()})
    print(list(values))
```

**Output:**

```
['DDR1', 'CYP2A6', 'DTX2P1', 'UPK3BP1', 'PMS2P11', 'MARCKSL1', 'CCL5', 'IK', 'ARL6IP5', 'EIF1AX', 'PFKP', 'PJA2', 'TLR4', 'GPNMB', 'TAGLN', 'COL1A1', 'CARMN', 'CD63']
```

**Note:**

By using a dictionary (rather than a set) we can preserve order